# Брать по дням данные погоды нужного города из gismeteo

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Хочу спросить можно ли как-то на php реализовать такую мысль: брать по дням данные погоды нужного города из `gismeteo` и выводить сообщение о том хорошая ли она или плохая? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5):

Спрашивали - отвечаем:

Можно, если у `gismeteo` есть соответствующий API.

Вот, например, [по этому адресу](http://informer.gismeteo.ru/xml/33345_1.xml) находится прогноз для (вроде бы, если 33345 это его код) Киева. Формат - `XML`. Чтобы использовать такого рода данные, программист должен написать парсер `XML`-данных. В вашем случае на `PHP`. `PHP` [предоставляет](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) удобные функции для работы.